# JSON to display SharePoint list choice column fields as visual checkbox, centered

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I tried to use the out-of-box SharePoint "checkbox" field in a SharePoint list, however, it does not visually display as a checkbox either in classic or modern view.  It was also cumbersome for users to edit.  So, I chose the "choice" field instead.

Is there JSON you can share that would display the choice as a visual checkbox, that is also centered in the column?

I've used the JSON below to get the checkbox, but it is not centered.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "iconName": "=if(@currentField,'CheckboxComposite','Checkbox')",
    "class": "=if(@currentField,'ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary','ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')+' ms-font-l'"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center the icon by making it a child of a `div` using flexbox:

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "justify-content": "space-evenly",
        "align-items": "center"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "=if(@currentField,'CheckboxComposite','Checkbox')",
                "class": "=if(@currentField,'ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary','ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')+' ms-font-l'"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Format in action]

Keep in mind this format will show an unchecked box when the choice field contains no value and a checked value when it does. It is not evaluating the choice value at all.

Comment: Thank you.  Are you aware of a method to have display checkboxes that a user can check and uncheck without entering Quick Edit Mode or double clicking to open the metadata editing sidebar?  Is there a way users can check or uncheck in the list without these extra clicks?

Comment: This can be accomplished through an SPFx Field Customizer. An example that uses a toggle control (but could be adapted to use a Checkbox) can be found here: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-field-toggle